# Image orientation HTML

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3

On my website, I'd like to display multiple images from an Amazon S3 Bucket. Everything works fine, but in Firefox, the pictures are sometimes orientated incorrectly. On my iPhone it works. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPhone knows how to read EXIF information from your image (witch retains your picture orientation among others) while a browser can't do that. I suggest you to upload them to the Amazon already rotated to what you want to see on your website.

Comment: Possibly could use this tool: https://github.com/alexstaubo/tootsie to rotate all the images in your S3 bucket based on EXIF orientation

Comment: Just make sure that if you're rotating before you upload that you're either stripping the orientation from the EXIF data or setting the orientation to `1`